# How to properly hide the cursor in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, hide, mouse-cursor

I try to hide the cursor. Works fine in Chrome but Safari isn't playing along. Whenever I drag the cursor (click+hold+move) in an area where the cursor is hidden it reappears.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<span>Test</span>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGeKpo